I tried using my system this morning and it's not booting
I tried using my system this morning and it's not booting.
I woke up this morning to this booting error on my system which was initially about apport-autoreport.service. So I disabled after reading some help online and also disabled the apport-autoreport.timer and path also, but the problem still persists. I tried to get into my grub Recovery mode, but I couldn't.

I'm still having the same problem, so I thought the issue was about the appimage (a video editor app) I downloaded last night which I removed and also FUSE which I had to install to make the appimage work, but the problem still persists after uninstalling the app.

There is no question here. A link is not a question. If you need some help ask a clear question and give details.

Let me try do that just my first time using the forum

@DavidDE you can help check now. Thanks.
